# Collation , convertion and importing from ssis with german chars

Tags: sql-server, unicode, import, ssis

My table is in SQL and contains only nvarchar columns. 
The columns collation is set to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` . I want to import from SSIS, using flat file connection, some data that contains german charachters like Ö, Ü, etc. 
In the flat file connection manager i have set the Code page:`65001 (UTF-8)` and the locale Germany, like in the attachement below and in the preview i have the data accordingly (Ex: Nürnberg).
However, when I execute the task and check the data in SQL table , it appears `NÃ¼rnberg`.

Am I missing something in this process?

[image]

Comment: Is your file UTF-8? You might want to try Code page: 1252 (ANSI - Latin I)?

Comment: What is the codepage in which the source data is encoded? I routinely import Japanese using SSIS. Locale is set to English(India) and codepage is set to 932 (ANSI/OEM - Japanese Shift-JIS). That is the codepage used to create the source file

Comment: @JarleBjørnbeth thanks for advice. I tried already with 1252 but the package will not be executed " cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types."

Comment: Ok. Are your nvarchar columns required, or could you just as well use varchar columns in your table?

Comment: @Raj Hi, I am using 65001 (UTF-8) as code page, with German (Germany) as locale. When I previe the datasource in SSIS, the description is correct with these settings. (Nürnberg not NÃ¼rnberg)

Comment: @JarleBjørnbeth there is no problem. I can also alter my columns to varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your file is not Unicode. Since you get the "cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types." error when using the 1252 ANSI code page, and you can change the datatype of your columns. I would just convert them to varchar. Since varchar is not Unicode the error should stop occurring.

The alternative would might be to do some thing like this:
[Import Package Error - Cannot Convert between Unicode and Non Unicode String Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299575/import-package-error-cannot-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-string-dat), but I think it would be easier to use varchar columns.